# Need tips to how this PHP function won't work

Tags: php

I have this function who should return the lvl of a user. All from 1-3, where 1 is normal. Everything works when a usr is 2-3, but not 1. The file will just return empty for a lvl 1.

```
$sql1 = db_query("SELECT * FROM `nyheter` WHERE `slettet`='nei' ORDER BY `id` DESC");

if($div->level($id) >= 2){
    while($r1 = mysqli_fetch_object($sql1)){
        echo " // html/php output here";
    }
} else {
    while($r2 = mysqli_fetch_object($sql1)){
        echo " // html/php output here ";
    }
}

function level($id){
        $q = db_query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `id`='$id'");
            while ($r = mysqli_fetch_object($q)){

        return $r->level;
            }
    }
```

I have tried to change it into

```
function level($id){
        $q = db_query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `id`='$id'");
            while ($r = mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
        if($r->level > 2 ){
            return $r->level;
        } else {
            return $r->level;
        }

    }
}
```

And

```
function level($id){
        $q = db_query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `id`='$id'");
            $r = mysqli_fetch_object($q);

        return $r->level;
    }
```

Comment: What you result you actually want?

Comment: When a usr is lvl 2, or higher they can delete news, so thats why I want it to be showed in two different ways. The output in echo is different. The problem is it only works for lvl >2 usrs

Comment: From where `$id` coming.? And, if it is working for `>=2`. Then, I assume it's not going to `else` part. Correct?

Comment: id comes from a config.php file `$id = $_SESSION['loggetinid'];` Yeah, it's not comes to the else part, its correct

Comment: Nobody who have any tips?